# Undefined index: input-post

Tags: php, pdo

Hola tengo este error

> Undefined index: input-post

El envío se hace desde el mismo index.php 
al parecer el error esta en 
 $post = $_POST['input-post'];
probe de moverlo fuera del 
if (!isset($_POST['publicar'])) {}

pero no logre arreglar el error alguien tiene idea?
todos los datos se incluyen en la db pero el unico campo que no se incluye es el del input-post 
esta es mi tabla en la base de datos

id  int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
usuario varchar(250)    utf8_unicode_ci
cuerpo  text    utf8_unicode_ci
date    timestamp

```
<?php session_start();
require('admincp/config.php');
require('function.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
  header('Location:'.RUTA.'');
}else {

}
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$post = $_POST['input-post'];
if (!isset($_POST['publicar'])) {
  $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web',"root","");
  $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO post(usuario, cuerpo) VALUES ($user,$post)");
}else {
  return false;
}
?>

          <form class="" action="" method="post">
            <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
              <div class="input-group-prepend" style="display:none;">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">@</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" name="input-post" class="form-control" placeholder="¿Que estas pensando?" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
            </div>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" name="publicar" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Compartir</button>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que estás accediendo a una variable que no existe, realiza la siguiente comprobación:

```
$post = isset($_POST['input-post']) ? $_POST['input-post'] : null;
```

Comment: Pero la variable no está en el formulario en la parte del name input? Ahora pruebo la comprobación

Comment: Si, está en el formulario pero cuando este se muestra por primera vez la variable $_POST no existe, lo que genera el warning a la hora de intentar acceder a 'input-post'. Cuando el formulario se envía ahí recién existe $_POST y sus respectivos valores del formulario.